# iAd. Is is essential to put code in .m file?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iad

I've got iAd showing, but just placing an aDBannerView object in my xib file.

Is it essential to implement something in .m file, or I can upload that version?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should add code for hiding and showing the banner view.
If no ad is available then you need to hide the banner view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with the way it works, then it's ok. You could finetune things in code, but that's your choice.

Comment: You should really only show the `ADBannerView` if you have an add. It very useless if you show the `ADBannerView` without an ad loaded.

Comment: There could be built-in background view for ad placement, to cover cases where ads a) ads are not yet received or b) you fail to receive ad. Both cases could leave ad view blank. Hiding it is one option, agreed.